# Data of attribute table is not showing on ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, attribute-table, arcgis-10.4

I have downloaded a point shapefile and when I can add this in my ArcMap 10.4. But the problem is when I try to open the attribute table it says this message and end up with bank rows.

[image]

It shows the number of features in the below but the table is empty. [image] How to solve it or the data is missing?

Comment: Can you share the link of the data where you downloaded?

Comment: It seems likely that the datafile is corrupt.

Comment: Test if the identity feature gives you any display of attribute information?

Comment: Yes This is the data Source-- http://spatial-analyst.net/book/system/files/meuse.zip

http://spatial-analyst.net/book/meusegrids

Comment: Yes the Identify feature can give ne me the info. Can i run Interpolation with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be with a field names `disc.m`

The best way is to **export the data to a feature class** in a file geodatabase.

Observe that the field name is converted to disc_m which is acceptable and the table opens without any issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It worked Perfectly! Thank you So much